# How to sort an array of strings by everything but the first letter

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

My array is expected to have elements that look like `"B1"` and `"C22"` for any letter `A-Z` and number `1-26`.
I need to sort this array numerically, so we don't consider the first character of the string when sorting. So that an array `{"B1", "A22", "C9"}` would be sorted to `{"B1", "C9", "A22"}`.

I have tried to take a substring, but it doesn’t work since I don’t know which strings will be of length 3 and which will be of length 2.

Comment: How would you sort `{"B9", "A22", "C9"}`?

Comment: with `substring` you don't need to know the exact length in advance if you just want to get everything but the first character of a string. There are 2 `substring `methods and one just takes a `beginIndex` as an argument and automatically adds everything from that `beginIndex` to the Strings end into the returned String. So a simple call of `substring(1)` should be all you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the array contains a huge number of elements, then you can replace `Arrays.sort()` with `Arrays.parallelSort()` to sort efficiently.

```
Arrays.sort(arr, 
    (ele1, ele2) -> ele1.substring(1).compareTo(ele2.substring(1)));
```

if you are confident that `substring(1)` only contains numeric value, then you can sort as below:

```
Arrays.sort(arr, (Comparator.comparingInt(element -> 
                            Integer.parseInt(element.substring(1)))));
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create your own comparator that ignores some of the characters :

```
Arrays.sort(s, new MyComparator());
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s));

class MyComparator implements Comparator<String> {


    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {

        // Remove the chars you are want to ignore from o1, o2 
        o1 = o1.substring(1);
        o2 = o2.substring(1);
        return Integer.compare(Integer.parseInt(o1),Integer.parseInt(o2));
        // return o1.compareTo(o2); see petr note bellow
    }
}
```

Comment: Given the question it should compare `Integer.compare(Integer.parseInt(o1.substring(1)),  Integer.parseInt(o2.substring(1)))` (not just strings) instead.

Comment: Depending on how OP wants "B9" and "C9" sorted relative to one another, I would check the return value of `Integer.compare` and if it's `0`, return `o1.compareTo(o2)` as a tie breaker.